# Puppeteer page request fails only on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, puppeteer

I've written a small javascript program using node (v12.16.2) and puppeteer (v2.1.1) that I'm trying to run on an AWS EC2 instance.  I'm doing a goto of the url appended to this.  It works fine on a local (non-AWS) linux machine with similar versions, but on the EC2, it fails, not showing the page at all.  I've tried running with headless=false and devtools=true.  In the browser console, I see this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at il_Ev (rs=ACT90oFtPziyty36T_zhgMUEStuCtJgAkQ:1862)
>       at il_Hv (rs=ACT90oFtPziyty36T_zhgMUEStuCtJgAkQ:1849)
>       at il_Yv.initialize (rs=ACT90oFtPziyty36T_zhgMUEStuCtJgAkQ:1867)
>       at il__i (rs=ACT90oFtPziyty36T_zhgMUEStuCtJgAkQ:270)
>       at il_Gl.il_Wj.H (rs=ACT90oFtPziyty36T_zhgMUEStuCtJgAkQ:322)
>       at rs=ACT90oFtPziyty36T_zhgMUEStuCtJgAkQ:1869

As I mentioned, this same code works fine on a different linux machine and just loaded inside a browser; no errors.  I'm stumped.  Does anyone know what might be going on?  Other pages, like google.com, load fine in the EC2, FYI. TIA.

Reid

https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fimg-s-msn-com.akamaized.net%2Ftenant%2Famp%2Fentityid%2FAACPW4S.img%3Fh%3D552%26w%3D750%26m%3D6%26q%3D60%26u%3Dt%26o%3Df%26l%3Df%26x%3D992%26y%3D672&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.msn.com%2Fen-us%2Flifestyle%2Fpets-animals%2F49-adorable-puppy-pictures-that-will-make-you-melt%2Fss-AACSrEY&tbnid=Ad7wBCCmAXPRDM&vet=12ahUKEwig1NfB0Y7oAhXGHc0KHSzuCMUQMygeegQIARBw..i&docid=jawDJ74qdYREJM&w=750&h=500&q=puppies&ved=2ahUKEwig1NfB0Y7oAhXGHc0KHSzuCMUQMygeegQIARBw

Here's an excerpt of the relevant code, which is pretty simple:

```
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
       headless: false,
       devtools: true,
       slowMo: 150
    });
   await browser.userAgent(
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
   );
   /* Get the first page rather than creating a new one unnecessarily. */
   let page = (await browser.pages())[0];
   await page.setViewport({
      width: 1524,
      height: 768
   });
   try {
await page.goto("https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fimg-s-msn-com.akamaized.net%2Ftenant%2Famp%2Fentityid%2FAACPW4S.img%3Fh%3D552%26w%3D750%26m%3D6%26q%3D60%26u%3Dt%26o%3Df%26l%3Df%26x%3D992%26y%3D672&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.msn.com%2Fen-us%2Flifestyle%2Fpets-animals%2F49-adorable-puppy-pictures-that-will-make-you-melt%2Fss-AACSrEY&tbnid=Ad7wBCCmAXPRDM&vet=12ahUKEwig1NfB0Y7oAhXGHc0KHSzuCMUQMygeegQIARBw..i&docid=jawDJ74qdYREJM&w=750&h=500&q=puppies&ved=2ahUKEwig1NfB0Y7oAhXGHc0KHSzuCMUQMygeegQIARBw", {
            timeout: 0,
//            waitUntil: ["load"]
//            waitUntil: ["networkidle2"]
});
     await page.waitForSelector('#irc_shc', {
        visible: true,
        timeout: 0
     });
   } catch(e) {
      console.log("error: e = ", e);
   }
```

Comment: Are you running the same version of node and puppeteer in both environments? Also show the code you are using.

Comment: I am.  I'll try to extract the code and add it to the question.

Comment: They could be blocking datacenter ip's, that's the most obvious reason.

Comment: @pguardiario It seems like something like that must be happening.  But is this documented anywhere?  I guess I could check the network tab in the devtools for anything suspicious.  Thanks.  (I don't have a lot of experience with EC2, by the way.)

Comment: pguardiario might be right.. have you tried to run it without explicitly setting the user agent?

Comment: Well, now I'm actually seeing this in my normal browser as well.  I'm sure it was working earlier.  Not sure what is going on with google....

Comment: @Sal, I did, no change, and the network tab showed no errors.  I think it's a google-side issue now, though.  Are you also seeing errors with the link?

Comment: I'm not sure of what the link you're opening is, but everything inside it has `display: none`. Try to remove `visible: true`

Comment: @Sal That's a good point, but I've since noticed that the page doesn't come up in my normal chrome browser, either.  It seems like the page is just broken.  Though, it may be by design; that's normally just a frame you get when you select an image in the list of them when you do an images search. It's worked on its own for months up until today.

Answer (score 0):

This was just a temporary google page error, it turns out.